# .htaccess Rewrite Rule with 3 parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to achive a 301 redirect with the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^daily_de.0.html?year=(.*)&month=(.*)&day=(.*)$ /extra/?date=$1.$2.$3 [R=301,L,NE]
```

The old page (daily_de.0.html including parameters) should redirect to the new page (e.g. /extra/?date=10.09.2015)

Not working so far :( Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match query string in a `RewriteRule`. Use it like this with a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^year=(\d+)&month=(\d+)&day=(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^daily_de\.0\.html$ /extra/?date=%1.%2.%3 [R=301,L,NC]
```